# Simple addition of variables between two functions

Tags: javascript, dom

Problem is the following. Each time, when button "Dodaj" is pressed an item is added to list in html. I need to show a total cost of items on separate element; in my case I used hidden input. I tried by declaring a global variable for total price in function for adding, and then read it in function Izracunaj. However, no value is displayed in hidden input.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var total= 0;

        function AddItem()
        {
            var startingPrice= document.getElementById('cena').value;
            var numbers= /^\d+$/;

            //Preverimo, če so kot cena vnešena samo števila
            if(startingPrice.match(numbers))
            {
                if(startingPrice< 10)
                {
                    //Preberemo vrednosti iz vnosnih polj
                    var productName= document.getElementById('productName').value; 
                    var price= document.getElementById('price').value; 

                    //Regularni izraz za validacijo imena
                    var letters= /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

                    if(!imeIzdelka.match(letters))
                    {
                        alert("Napačen vnos imena. Vnašate lahko samo črke.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Pridobimo seznam in ustvarimo nov element seznama
                        var list= document.getElementById('list');
                        var product= document.createElement('li');

                        var fullName= productName+ " - " + price+ "€";

                        //Novemu elementu določimo vrednost
                        product.innerHTML = fullName;

                        //Vstavimo element
                        list.insertBefore(product, list.firstChild);

                        _price = parseFloat(price);
                        total= total+ _price;
                    }
                }
                else if(startingPrice> 10)
                {
                    //Preberemo vrednosti iz vnosnih polj
                    var productName= document.getElementById('productName').value;
                    var price= document.getElementById('price').value;              

                    var letters= /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;

                    if(!productName.match(letters))
                    {
                        alert("Napačen vnos imena. Vnašate lahko samo črke.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Pridobimo seznam in ustvarimo nov element seznama
                        var list= document.getElementById('list');
                        var product= document.createElement('li');

                        //Spremenimo barvo na rdečo
                        product.style.color = "red";

                        //Združimo vrednosti 
                        var fullName= productName + " - " + price+ "€";

                        //Novemu elementu določimo vrednost
                        product.innerHTML = fullName;

                        //Vstavimo element
                        list.insertBefore(product, list.firstChild);

                        _price = parseFloat(price);
                        total= total+ _price;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Kot ceno lahko vnašate samo cela števila.");
            }

            //Vrnemo skupno ceno
            return total;
        }
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Function Calculate()
        {
            var price = AddItem();
            document.getElementById('totalPrice').value= price;
        }
    </script>
```

I am sorry for code not being in english language.

Here are the inputs:

```
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add Item" onClick = AddItem() />
<input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate" onClick = Calculate() />
<input type="hidden" id="totalPrice" />
```

Comment: Tranlating variables finished. I think.

Comment: Any error in the console

Comment: Can you create a demo like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z87t6/1/

Comment: Cena means price in my language.

Comment: There is also an error in console saying: Uncaught ReferenceError: Izracunaj is not defined onclick and Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 0):

hidden inputs use value not innerHTML

```
document.getElementById('skupnaCena').innerHTML = cena;
```

need to be

```
document.getElementById('skupnaCena').value = cena;
```

You also need to cobvert strings to numbers using parseFloat() before you add them.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. The problem was, that I was trying to display the total price in "input type = hidden". I changed it to text with readonly attribute, and it works.